# Find smallest subgroups

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, infinite-groups

I'm struggling with this. Let $G$ be an infinite cyclic group and let $g$ be its generator ($G=\langle g \rangle$). Find the smallest subgroup that contains $g^4$ and $g^6$. By definition it is $\langle\{g^4,g^6\}\rangle$ but the problem requires me to give a generator for this subgroup I would appreciate any advice

Comment: Would $g^4$ alone work? Would $g^6$ alone work? If not, can you think of another element that will do the trick?

Comment: Thanks to you all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the generator of any subgroup of the cyclic group $\langle g\rangle$ must be a power of $g$, say $g^k$. Now for some $m$, $g^m\in\langle g^k\rangle$ implies that $m$ is a multiples of $k$. Hence the smallest subgroup of $\langle g\rangle$ that contains both $g^4$ and $g^6$ must be $\langle g^2\rangle$ as $2=\gcd(4,6)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** So let $g^x$ be in that, then you should be able to write it as $$g^{4\cdot a+6\cdot b}=g^{2(2\cdot a+3\cdot b)}.$$ Can you show that every single number that you can imagine can be written as $2\cdot a+3\cdot b$? If it helps, notice that $2\cdot 2-3\cdot 1=1.$

Answer (score 2):

The smallest subgroups containing $g^4$ and $g^6$ is the subgroup generated by these elements, and, the group being commutative, it is equal to the set of elements
$$(g^4)^r(g^6)^s=g^{4r+6s}\quad (r,s\in\mathbf Z).$$
Now the ideal of $\mathbf Z$ generated by two elements is the ideal generated by their g.c.d., so  $$\langle\, g^4,g^6\rangle=\langle\, g^2\rangle.$$